# window.open() is not Working when Passing variable in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am getting stuck on my Project for last 2 days. I am using window.open() in 
       a Jsp for button type input. as:-

**HTML**

```
     <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="button" value="Report" id="btn1" 
     onclick="window.open('<%= url %>')"></td>
```

But when I pass String at the place of url in window.open then it works fine.

**Javascript:**

```
    onclick="window.open('<%= "http://www.google.com" %>')"
```

please help me, 
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't know why your JavaScript isn't working, then show us your *JavaScript*, not the JSP that generates it.

Comment: I am saying window.open('<%= url %>') is not working that is first case

Comment: If you don't know why your JSP isn't working then show us your expected output and your actual output and don't just tell us that the JavaScript doesn't work.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to store in 'url' and how?

Comment: Sir I want to give control to a servlet which will generate pdf in new tab for this reason I am to passing url in window.open() method in jsp  .  This url contains the url of that servlet and I have already printed in it prints correct value but it not works i.e. not gives the control to that particular url. But when I hard code that in window then it works

Comment: post how you are storing url of servlet in 'url' maybe you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with the code. Hope you have initialized the url before . may be the variable url be empty.